# Translucent overlay all over the screen on top of a video without using backdrop-filter

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a code to add a translucent overlay on a playing video:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  addBlurOverlay();
}, 2000);

function addBlurOverlay() {
  const clip = document.querySelector(".blur-overlay");
  clip.classList.add("focused");
}
```

```css
.focused {
  animation: focusedShow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes focusedShow {
  from {
    backdrop-filter: blur(0);
    background-color: rgba(35, 33, 36, 0);
  }
  to {
    backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
    background-color: rgba(35, 33, 36, 0.7);
  }
}


video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.blur-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  background: none;
}

.clip-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #0b0e12;
}
```

```html
<div class="clip-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="blur-overlay"></div>
      <video id="clip" autoplay="true" loop>
      <source src="http://optus-sport-prod-design.s3.amazonaws.com/saleshero/video/WWC_BANNER_720p_v2.mp4" type="video/mp4" type="video/mp4">
       </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code works fine with an issue which made the whole approach (I mean using `backdrop-filter: blur(100px)` to blur the screen) unusable in my case.

Any other animations that is added above the blurred screen takes a lot of GPU. This issue won't happen in simple blur like this: `filter: blur(100px)`.

Is there any solution to add the same functionality without using `backdrop-filter`?

**NOTE: I don't want to blur the video itself.**

Please help I'm ruined...